# WordPress Multisite dashboards redirect to homepage

Tags: multisite, admin, dashboard

I hope you can help me. I've got a WordPress Multisite install, and have a few subsides. For the main site, when I try to open the dashboard, it opens fine. But for all subsides, when I try to open the dashboard it just takes me to the subsite's homepage.

I'm not sure this makes any difference, but each of the subsites has it's own domain. So for example, the main site is [www.site.com](http://www.site.com), and if I go to [www.site.com/wp-admin/](http://www.site.com/wp-admin/) I get the admin panel no problem. But for a subsite, which I created as [www.site.com/sub/](http://www.site.com/sub/) and is now [www.sub.com](http://www.sub.com), if I try to open the dashboard from the main admin panel I just get taken to [www.sub.com](http://www.sub.com), and trying to open [www.sub.com/wp-admin/](http://www.sub.com/wp-admin/) opens the same page.

I have just tested creating another Subsite and not changing it's url/domain and that works fine, so here must be something I've done wrong when adding the domains?

Any help you can give would be great, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check that the url for sub.com is set correctly in [www.site.com/wp-admin/network/sites.php](http://www.site.com/wp-admin/network/sites.php) ?